# Can I be intolerant of milk even if it's not a medical issue for me?

Tags: word-usage

Even though I have no medical ailments that are caused by consuming milk/dairy, I'm still just not a fan of it.

So would it be completely incorrect to say "I can't tolerate milk/I am becoming intolerant to milk"?

Comment: You can say you *can't tolerate* milk, but saying you're *intolerant to* milk doesn't communicate what you're trying to say.

Comment: Why not just say you don't like milk/dairy???

Comment: You can say, ["milk doesn't agree with me"](http://www.upmc.com/patients-visitors/education/nutrition/pages/milk-and-your-lactose-restricted-diet.aspx) That could mean you either dislike it, or that it makes your tum feel a bit queasy or odd. [Milk doesn't sit well (with me)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255790/what-is-the-meaning-of-milk-doesnt-sit-with-me-well), is also another way of explaining why you dislike it. Or simply just say "I don't like milk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is technically correct to say you are intolerant of milk.  You do not tolerate it, in that you do not like it.

Since lactose-intolerance is such a well-known medical condition, saying that you're intolerant would tend to lead a reader into believing you have that medical issue.  This could lead to a misunderstanding, since lactose, the sugar in milk that lactose-intolerant people can't digest, is also present in all dairy products like cheese.

I would frame it in the form of taste.

> I detest milk.
>
> I am growing to dislike milk.

Answer (score 2):

"Intolerant" seems to get you get you off on the wrong foot here. You seem to be looking for a way of expressing a preference or a disliking whereas tolerant/intolerant specifically reflects an ability to handle, e.g.:

**"used, usually in compounds, to describe a person who is not able to eat a particular type of food or take a particular type of medicine without it having a bad effect:"**
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intolerant

I would think along the lines of "dislike" or "prefer".

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of the word ‘tolerant’ or ‘intolerant’ here because it has a precise medical and genetic meaning in the term [‘lactose-intolerant’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactose_intolerance), and might therefore lead to confusion.

(Lactose intolerance is not actually an ailment, as before the domestication of cattle etc. the normal situation was that the ability to digest lactose in milk was lost after infants were weaned.)

Use the simple English expression that you would for any other food you disliked, e.g.

> I [detest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/detest) milk
>
> I can’t [stand](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stand) milk

or if your aversion is not so great, simply

> I don’t [like](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/like) milk very much

There is no virtue in using fancy-sounding words that you are not sure about when simple ones will do.